# How to debug SQL error correctly on DBeaver, if details are only related to JAVA error messages

Tags: sql, dbeaver

Is there a better way to debug SQL code, instead of being struggling with JAVA error messages on DBeaver Client v22?

In this scenario SQL execution has returned an error in the UNION statement, which is related to an unidentified query.

[image]

SQL script has 1023 lines, and around 20 queries containing UNION.
AS I don't want to run every query isolated...

How would I narrow down and detail further the SQL error. which line is it? what query?
what are the last lines from the stack?